# Cython Compile Error: Python3 Compatibility

Tags: python, cython, anaconda

I am running `Python 3.4.4 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (x86_64)` on `OS X Yosemite`. My Cython's version is `0.23.4`. I'm trying to embed some very trivial Cython code `test.pyx` into C code `testcc.c`. The problem is, if I use `python2.7-config` then everything works well (Python 2.7 is the built-in version on OS X). However if I use `python3.4-config` the following errors raised:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_inittest", referenced from:
      _main in testcc-b22dcf.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have to use Python3 since all my other codes are written in it. Please help me solve this problem.

---

The following are my source files:

`test.pyx`:

```
cdef public void pythonAdd(int[] a):
    a[1] = 5
    a[0] = 4
```

`testcc.c`:

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "test.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Py_Initialize();
    inittest();
    int a [2] = {0 , 0};
    pythonAdd(a);
    printf("fist: %d, second: %d", a[0], a[1]);
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

And Compiling those two files using following `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext = Extension("testc", sources=["test.pyx"])

setup(name="testc", ext_modules=cythonize(ext))
```

The following is the command I compile those c files:

```
ldflags:=$(shell $(python3.4-config) --ldflags)
cflags:=$(shell $(python3.4-config) --cflags)
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
cython test.pyx
gcc $(cflags) $(ldflags) test.c testcc.c -o cysvm.out
```

---

Update:

I changed the `inittest()` to `PyInit_test()` as Jim suggested. The code compiles successfully. However when I run `./cysvm.out` the following errors occured:

```
./cysvm.out
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fff772f5300 (most recent call first):
```

### Update

I solved this by adding the following line before `Py_Initialize();` in my `c` code:

```
Py_SetPythonHome(L"/PATH/to/python3");
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your second issue could again be solved with setting `PYTHONHOME` to the path obtained from `python3.4-config --exec-prefix`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to the fact that in Python `3.x` initialization of modules is not performed by calling `init<module_name>` but rather with `PyInit_<module_name>` (See [**`PEP 3121`**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3121/#specification)). So, if you are linking with Python `3.x` and executing via `3.x` you need to change the initialization call.

In short, changing the call that initializes the module from:

```
inittest();
```

To:

```
PyInit_test();
```

and recompiling, should do the trick.

---

As for your second problem, an alternate solution other than using `Py_SetPythonHome` is setting [**`PYTHONHOME`**](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHOME) to the output of `python3.4-config --exec-prefix` (or [**`sys.exec_prefix`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exec_prefix)) prior to compilation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It did work for compiling. But when I run the output file some new errors occurred. Would you please see the update in my answer? Thanks!

Comment: I've already solved that problem. Thank you all the same. However would you please provide me some documentation about embedding Cython into C? Most materials I found either incomplete or outdated.

Comment: Hm, embedding is not the most common situation so `Cython` docs don't really focus on it much. In general, one book I have found that sheds a bit of light on it is [here](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/learning-cython-programming). Other than this, you mostly need to google around for other resourses like [EmbeddingCython](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/EmbeddingCython) from the Cython Wiki or the Embedding How to from the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/index.html).

Comment: Those are very helpful. Thank you so much!